# Sunday date imputation

Tags: python, pandas

```
    Date
0   06-03-16
1   08-05-16
2   15-05-16
3   22-05-16
4   29-05-16
5   05-06-16
6   31-07-16
```

I have the above dates and some of the Dates are missing between 06-03-16 and 08-05-16.
Every date is a Sunday and the missing dates are also Sundays.
How to impute missing Sunday dates in a pandas data frame?

Comment: I don't think ['impute'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impute) means what you think it means. What do you think 'impute' means?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) selecting the mimimum and maximum dates as `start` and `end` respectively, and setting `freq='W-SUN'`:

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=min(df.Date), end=max(df.Date), 
                           freq='W-SUN').strftime('%d-%m-%Y').tolist(), 
                           columns = ['Date'])

       Date
0   06-03-2016
1   13-03-2016
2   20-03-2016
3   27-03-2016
4   03-04-2016
5   10-04-2016
6   17-04-2016
7   24-04-2016
8   01-05-2016
9   08-05-2016
10  15-05-2016
11  22-05-2016
12  29-05-2016
13  05-06-2016
14  12-06-2016
15  19-06-2016
16  26-06-2016
17  03-07-2016
18  10-07-2016
19  17-07-2016
20  24-07-2016
21  31-07-2016
```

Make sure the `Date`  column is in `datetime`  format:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d-%m-%y')
```

Comment: Dang, 10 seconds ahead of me :). A side note: you can just use `freq='W'`, it's the same as 'W-SUN'.